# Running Q Exp in a GhcMonad

Tags: haskell, template-haskell, ghc-api

I'm looking for something with a type similar to this:

```
runQExpDynamically :: (GhcMonad m) => Q Exp -> m Dynamic
```

Docs: [GhcMonad](http://www.haskell.org/platform/doc/2013.2.0.0/ghc-api/GhcMonad.html#t:GhcMonad), [Q](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.9.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH-Syntax.html#t:Q) [Exp](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.9.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH-Syntax.html#t:Exp), [Dynamic](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.3.1.0/docs/Data-Dynamic.html),

I'm looking for ways to combine two of my code examples; one for [dynamically evaluating haskell code](https://gist.github.com/worldsayshi/8853946) and one for [composing haskell dynamically using template haskell](https://gist.github.com/worldsayshi/afe2dda684f76cf784cf). In other words run Q Exp:ressions in a GhcMonad.

I will work on this problem and I should document here as I go.

#### Some ideas

The approach that I currently find workable is to serialize the expression and feed it into the dynamic evaluation. The serialization will have to be done inside the Q monad somehow. I might be able to use that Exp implements the [Ppr prettyprinter](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.9.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH-Ppr.html#t:Ppr) class. However, I might loose some type safety this way? There might be a cleaner (more hygenic"?) way. I should look a bit more into [Data.Dynamic](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.3.1.0/docs/Data-Dynamic.html) to understand how dynamic values work.

**edit:** I realize now that Dynamic only represent values, while I want to run Q Exp 'declarations'. I want to add datatypes to a dynamic context.

Comment: It seems like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14460095/439034) more or less does this using the serialization approach. But it might be possible to do it in a more hygienic way.